# Is there a way to download Met Office rainfall radar images?

Tags: c#, image, api, internationalization, weather

I am developing a weather radar app in c#. It currently works only in the United States, because I have not found a way to download any international radar. For the United States, there is an easy way to access radar from the national weather service, they keep all the radar images [here](http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg) and all the maps and overlays [here](http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Overlays) and documentation [here](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/jetstream/doppler/ridge_download.htm). Is there any official radar feed for Met Office, or any other way to access the radar images? I have poked around on their [website](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/) with no luck.

Comment: Have you looked at their DataPoint service?  More specifically - http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/product/rainfall-radar-map-layer/detailed-documentation and http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/support/observation-layer-capabilities

Comment: That works great. If you change it to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Met Office has a service called [DataPoint](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint).  Get an [API key](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/support/API) and check out their [radar capabilities](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/datapoint/support/observation-layer-capabilities).